# How to use bootstrap locally with flask

Tags: python, templates, flask, offline, flask-bootstrap

I did my best to try to use bootstrap locally with flask on a computer (without internet connection).
My folders are like that :
Templates

```
-layout.html
-bootstrap
    -css
        -bootstrap.min.css
    -js
        -bootstrap.min.js
        -jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js
        -popper.min.js
```

And in my layout.html file, I use bootstrap with these lines :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
```

in the head tag and

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in the body tag.
If I launch just this html file, the bootstrap is working but if I use this template in my app.py file like that :

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home/")
def home():
    return render_template("layout.html")
```

The bootstrap isn't working...
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the entire bootstrap folder in a directory named `static` then use `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css>`

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working... (I changed its to href='static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' and like this it works if I open the layout.html but not with using flask...)

Comment: Is your layout.html file in the templates folder

Comment: yes it is in the templates folder

Comment: Btw the static folder shouldn't be in templates folder

Comment: Any idea what to do now if i want to use js as it's not static ? like bootstrap.min.js or popper.min.js...

Comment: Js should be in the static folder

Comment: Oh okay it works but it seems strange to me to put it in a static file as it's not used for statics tools. Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842914/11716841  check this out